# Include several text format commands in html

Tags: html, format, gorilla

Very basic question: I want to center align a text and increase the font size in html for gorilla software and I can't seem to find how.

Here are the two separate commands:

```
<p style="font-size: 150%;">This is my text. %</p>'

<p style="text-align: center;">This is my text.</p>
```

I tried something like that but it didn't work:

```
<p style="font-size: 150%;" style="text-align: center;">This is my text. %</p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question use a semicolon

```
<p style="font-size: 150%; text-align: center;">This is my text. %</p>
```

but better - use a class and a stylesheet:

```css
.bigCenter {
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="bigCenter">This is my text. %</p>
```